# Micro controller based security system using sonar system

Tags: sonarqube

I'm a student engineer in telecommunication and I have to do a project on Micro controller based security system using sonar system. Can anyone please help me in designing the project? Any advice will be most welcome. Thanking you for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 0):

What is your project about? Designing the security system or programmming it?
If programming, you have to use a language supported by SonarQube http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library

Regards

Comment: I must do the whole implementation that is both designing and programming. The sonar should be mounted on a stepper motor which will be use to scan a room. I will be glad if you could help me in a way or another, thanking you.

Comment: You are in the wrong group. Here we talk about analyzing code quality with a tool named Sonar, lately SonarQube. Nothing about hardware sonar